# How can I use group by and lookup together in MongoDB for collections with multiple filters?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, nosql, lookup

How to use group by and lookup at the same query in mongoDB?

I have a a mongo db collection filter_weights:

```
` {
    "category": "laptops",
    "counter": 7,
    "filter_id": "brands"
  }
```

I have the second collection called filter_options_weights:

```
 {
    "category": "laptops",
    "counter": 2,
    "filter_id": "brands", 
    "filter_option_value": "Dell"
  }, 
` {
    "category": "laptops",
    "counter": 5,
    "filter_id": "brands", 
    "filter_option_value": "Apple"
  }
```

the outpout that i want to get is:

```
{
    "category": "laptops",
    "counter": 7, 
    "filter_id": "brands"
    "filter_option_value": [{"Dell": 2}, {"Apple": 5}]
  },
```

I tried to do smth like this

```
`db.filter_weights.aggregate(
    {$match: {$and: [{category: "smartfony"}]}},
    {$group: {        _id : "$filter_id",        totalSum :{$sum: "$counter"}        }},
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "filter_values_weights",
                localField:"filter_id",
                foreignField: "filter_id",
                as :"filter_id"
            }
    })`
```

but i dont understand how to use lookup and the group by at the same query

Answer (score 0):

1. `$match` stage
2. `$group` - Group by `filter_id`. The output after this stage will no longer have the `filter_id` field, you should refer to `_id`. While to get `category`, you may consider using the `$first` operator.
3. `$lookup` - Use `_id` as localField. The join collection should be *filter_options_weights* but not *filter_values_weights*. And return the joined collection result as `filter_option_value`.
4. `$set` - Set the `filter_option_value` field by transforming it into a new array via `$map`, set each document with key: `filter_option_value` and value: `counter`.

```
db.filter_weights.aggregate([
  /* $match stage, */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$filter_id",
      category: {
        $first: "$category"
      },
      counter: {
        $sum: "$counter"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "filter_options_weights",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "filter_id",
      as: "filter_option_value"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      filter_option_value: {
        $map: {
          input: "$filter_option_value",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [
              [
                {
                  k: "$$this.filter_option_value",
                  v: "$$this.counter"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_vmXRNoyacL)